# extract a string between 2 strings in python?

Tags: python

I need to one give me the string between `~` and `^`

i have string like this

`:::ABC???,:::DEF???`

I need to get the string between them with python

I want to do all this because i am trying to extract text from an html page. like this example

```
<td class="cell-1">
    <div><span class="value-frame">&nbsp;~ABC^,~DEF^</span></div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want ABC and DEF , so you need write re like this (.*?)

```
import re
target = ' <td class="cell-1"><div><span class="value-frame">&nbsp;~ABC^,~DEF^</span></div></td>'
matchObj = re.findall(r'~(.*?)\^', target)
print matchObj 
# ['ABC', 'DEF']
```

you can learn more about re module

Comment: what does it mean `(.*?)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `isalpha()` function in a generator expression. Then combine the characters as a single `string` using `join()`.

```
def extract_string(s):
    return ''.join(i for i in s if i.isalpha())
```

**Sample output:**

```
print extract_string(':::ABC???,:::DEF???')
>>> ABCDEF
```

However that is only for extracting all characters, if you want to extract only characters between `~...^`:

```
import re
def extract_string(s):
    match = re.findall(r"~([a-zA-z]*)\^", s)
    return match
```

**Sample output:**

```
s = '&nbsp;~ABC^,~DEF^'
print extract_string(s)
>>> ['ABC', 'DEF']
```

Just a side note: if you're parsing **HTML** using *regex* and/or *string manipulation*, as the [famous S.O. reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) suggests, please use a HTML parser; such as the [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) library instead :D!